# How do I use wget to fetch a file from a location other than the default server context root?

Tags: wget

I am able to fetch files that are in a server's context root.  For example, `wget https://<ServerDomain>:<ServerPort>/index.html` works with no problem.  However, I need to fetch a file that is not in the server context root (or a subdirectory of that).  As a test , I tried to fetch a file from the parent directory of the context root using `wget https://<ServerDomain>:<ServerPort>/../filename` but this returns

```
Resolving <ServerDomain> (<ServerDomain>)... <ServerIPAddress>
Connecting to <ServerDomain> (<ServerDomain>)|<ServerIPAddress>|:<ServerPort>... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-01-07 18:49:56 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

What is the "path format" to be used in such a case?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the server is properly configured, you can't. Otherwise an attacker could just download e.g. `example.com/../../../../../../../etc/passwd` or any file in the system.

Comment: Thanks melpomene - I was wondering if that was the issue.  Is the best practice/only solution in this case to copy the desired file to the context root before wget?  Or, is there a better way to fetch a file not located there?

Answer (score 0):

melpomene's comment resolved the issue:

> If the server is properly configured, you can't. Otherwise an attacker could just download e.g. `example.com/../../../../../../../etc/passwd` or any file in the system.